# How can I change validation with alert message to validation with red borders around textboxes?

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net

I am able to validate dynamically generated textboxes within gridview control with the following script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ValidateEmptyValue() { 
    var gv = document.getElementById("<%= Gridview1.ClientID %>"); 
    var tb = gv.getElementsByTagName("input"); 

    for (var i = 0; i < tb.length; i++) { 
        if (tb[i].type == "text") { 
            if (tb[i].value < 1) { 
                 alert("Field cannot be blank!");
                return false; 
            } 
        } 
    } 
    return true; 
}
</script>
```

This works fine.

However, I would like to change from

```
alert("Field cannot be blank!");
```

to

red borders around textboxes?

Thanks in advance

```
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
            <ItemTemplate>
            <label ID="lblTitle">Your title<span style="color:#ff0000">*</span></label><br />
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator id="RequiredFieldValidator2" Font-Bold="true" 
                BorderColor="Red" BorderWidth="1" SetFocusOnError="true" 
            runat="server" 
            Height="16px" ErrorMessage="REQUIRED FIELD" ControlToValidate="txtsourcename" />
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtsourcename" runat="server" style="width:200px;"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Adress">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtsourceaddress" runat="server" style="width:200px;"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Income">
            <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:TextBox ID="txtsourceincome" runat="server" style="width:200px;"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>

    '//generated HTML code
<table cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="Gridview1" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">Name</th><th scope="col">Adress</th><th scope="col">Income</th><th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>
            <label ID="lblTitle">Your title<span style="color:#ff0000">*</span></label><br />
            <span id="Gridview1_RequiredFieldValidator2_0" style="display:inline-block;border-color:Red;border-width:1px;border-style:solid;font-weight:bold;height:16px;visibility:hidden;">REQUIRED FIELD</span>
                <input name="Gridview1$ctl02$txtsourcename" type="text" id="Gridview1_txtsourcename_0" style="width:200px;" />
            </td><td>
                <input name="Gridview1$ctl02$txtsourceaddress" type="text" id="Gridview1_txtsourceaddress_0" style="width:200px;" />
            </td><td>
                 <input name="Gridview1$ctl02$txtsourceincome" type="text" id="Gridview1_txtsourceincome_0" style="width:200px;" />
            </td><td><a href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;Gridview1&#39;,&#39;Delete$0&#39;)">Delete</a></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td align="right">
             <input type="submit" name="Gridview1$ctl03$ButtonAdd" value="Add More" onclick="return ValidateEmptyValue();WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;Gridview1$ctl03$ButtonAdd&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" id="Gridview1_ButtonAdd" />
            </td><td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: instead of `alert()` use `tb[i].style.border = "solid 1px red";`

Comment: @AZee, thank you very much. It works for one textbox.

I have three textbox controls on gridview1. Is it possible to make it put borders on all three at same time?

It is not possible, then I stick with this solution.

Comment: I just updated the code! @kenny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you need to change style property of your input fields use `style.border`.

Below is the updated version of your code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ValidateEmptyValue() { 
    var is_valid = true,
        gv = document.getElementById("<%= Gridview1.ClientID %>"),
        tb = gv.getElementsByTagName("input");

    for (var i = 0; i < tb.length; i++) { 
        if (tb[i].type == "text") { 
            if (tb[i].value < 1) { 
                tb[i].style.border = "solid 1px red";
                is_valid = false;
            } 
        }
    }

    return is_valid;
}
</script>
```

Comment: thanks but it is still highlighting one textbox instead of three.

I have shown the three textboxes above.

Comment: Sorry I am not familiar with asp but if you can show me generated `HTML` that will help. @Kenny

Comment: I have updated the code above to show the generated HTML.

I *THINK* that the reason yours worked with all three textboxes is because it has one name.

Comment: I think the problem is that your each textbox is into a different GridView. Either you need to `var gv1 = document.getElementById("<%= Gridview1.ClientID %>");` `var gv2 = document.getElementById("<%= Gridview2.ClientID %>");` `var gv3 = document.getElementById("<%= Gridview3.ClientID %>");` or wrap all three grid views into one container and assign it a unique id

Comment: Where did you see those?

I updated the code because I added more code there than I wanted,

Comment: From your updated code, please assign an ID to the table and select it with that ID. https://jsfiddle.net/m7yh4jv1/1/

Comment: That was not the updated code. That code was already there. I was posting the updated code before your last post

Comment: Yeah before my last comment I didn't notice that you updated the code,. Another solution is to check the inputs one by one by their `id`. Updating my code.

Comment: At first I didn't notice you were returning the value on your `onClick` event. Thank you for selecting my answer :-)

Comment: Yes, even though I awarded you the points and by the way, I really appreciate your help, if you still think you can help, that would be appreciated, Otherwise, I keep playing around with till I can fix it because my boss prefers all three boxes highlighted at same time.

Comment: Oh Did you notice I updated my code and this final update works like a charm for all three boxes.

Comment: Oh no, I did not. This is awesome. Thanks so much.

Comment: You are Welcome! @Kenny